# Deleted columns should not affect the summation values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here, I am using the month wise report from January to December and I had the grand total column. Each month wise report consists of five columns named age, gender, code, education code and area code. All the data is in binary. Using the summation formula, I added the totals in the grand total. Now, I need to get only few months report. For that, I deleted the other months and its showing a #REF in the grand total.

If I take only first column in the grand total, its summation looks like =SUM(B4,I4,P4,W4,AD4,AK4,AR4,AY4).

Can any one suggest how to do this using OFFSET or any other formula in Excel?

Comment: " I deleted the other months".. is that a sheet, or a row?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a SUMIF:

When you put in single cell values like that deletion will cause errors.

Have you tried:

=Sumif(B1:zz1,"AGE",B4:zz4)?

I arbitrarily assumed  column labels are in row 1 and the data doesn't extend past column ZZ.

In the future I would recommend using a table and filtering by month rather than deleting data.